# Is it possible to unit test the parameters that I pass to the function in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

In this scenario:

In FileA:

```
from FileB import BJob

class EasyJob
    def __init__():
        self.job = BJob()
    
    def launch_job_in_A():
        self.job.launch_job_in_B(cpu=100, memory=200)
```

In FileB:

```
class BJob():
    def __init__():
        pass

    def launch_job_in_B(cpu=0, memory=0):
        do_some_thing(cpu, memory)
        ...
```

Is there a way to write a unit test for launch_job_in_A() function and also verify whether we do pass cpu=100 and memory=200 to launch_job_in_B() function successfully?

Broadly question is like, is it possible to check the parameter we passed to the function?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, if you're testing `FileA`, you can create a stub that gets called instead of `FileB`, and that stub would check that its `launch_job_in_B` was called, and with the right parameters. This might not be easy to do, but it's possible. (Next you'll ask me how, but I don't actually know, my comment is just a conceptual suggestion, not a specific Python solution.)

Comment: The [mocking part](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html) of pytest may be of use here. Or perhaps there's another part in the pytest guide that can be of help. I think it'll be useful to peruse the pytest documentation, even if you don't use pytest.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) via [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) and then use the [`assert_called_once_with`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once_with) method to verify the function call:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from FileA import EasyJob


class TestEasyJob(TestCase):
    def test_launch_job_in_A(self):
        with patch('FileB.BJob.launch_job_in_B') as mock:
            job = EasyJob()
            job.launch_job_in_A()
        mock.assert_called_once_with(cpu=100, memory=200)


unittest.main()
```

Comment: Note that patching `FileB.BJob.launch_job_in_B` mocks *every* call to `BJob.launch_job_in_B`. The test assumes there is one and only one call to `BJob.launch_job_in_B` making it [glass-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) and fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would replace `self.job` with a [mock object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) and its `launch_job_in_B` with a mock method.

This would be easier if there was an option to pass in the BJob, rather than hard coding it. This avoids having to mock every call to `launch_job_in_B` which might have unexpected side effects. This also makes the class more flexible.

```
from FileB import BJob

class EasyJob
    def __init__(bjob=BJob()):
        self.job = bjob
    
    def launch_job_in_A():
        self.job.launch_job_in_B(cpu=100, memory=200)
```

Now we can mock the method just for a single object.

```
from FileA import EasyJob
from FileB import BJob
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

# Set up the mocked object and method.
mock_bjob = BJob()
# If it needs to return something, configure that.
mock_bjob.launch_job_in_B() = MagicMock()

# Make the EasyJob with the mocked BJob
ejob = EasyJob(bjob=mock_bjob)

# Call the method in question.
ejob.launch_job_in_A()

# Check if the method was called with the correct arguments.
mock_bjob.method.assert_called_once_with(cpu=100, memory=200)
```

`BJob.launch_job_in_B` would be tested in its own unit test.